# Is it possible to convert JSON variable names on-the-fly in go?

Tags: json, go, rename, capitalization

I'm currently implementing some function that prints a complex structure into JSON. It needs the variable names to be lower-case, which would mean putting a lot of JSON tags all over the place. I tried converting the structure to map, then changing the capitalisation and converting it back, but that converted int64s into float64s and messed a few other things up.

Is there some way to easily convert JSON variable names on-the-fly in go?

Comment: There is a feature called MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES in jackson. It will ignore caseSensitivity

Comment: No. You have to do this yourself. If you are looking for a third-party library: So is not the right place to look.

Answer (score 1):

JSON Tags would the your best option, if maps are not an option for you.

Else you would need to manually modify the output of `json.Marshal`, which is a `[]byte` change it to a string, parse through it and convert all the keys to lower case.